# How do I toggle source mapping in Safari 7?

Tags: safari, source-maps, safari-web-inspector

The Safari 7 inspector is marvelously line-mapping compiled javascript back to the coffeescript it came from. There are times, though, when I want to interact directly with the compiled javascript in inspector. How do I toggle source mapping off so I can play with the raw javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Safari 7, Source Maps are not something that you have to toggle on or off they are just always on like resources are always available in the web developer tool. If you want to jump to the raw source you can:

> "...Command-click the file name to jump to the position in the original source file."

The [Safari Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH3-SW2) has more info on this.

Comment: Great! Turns out you can also command-click any word / token in the coffeescript and it jumps to that token in the raw javascript. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Command clicking a word in the source map does not take me to the original source file. It merely creates additional cursors.