# Prevent Server from Viewing Sourcemap in Safari in React

Tags: reactjs, safari, webpack

I'm currently using React and I have a few node modules that have references to Sourcemaps like so:

```
 //# sourceMappingURL=is-object.js.map
```

While my site loads fine with Chrome and Firefox, my site runs into an error in Safari where it attempts to retrieve these sourceMapUrls which don't exist.

The current solution I've found while on Stack Overflow was just to delete that line of code (Which I've done for bootstrap ect). However, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do that.

I can technically go and delete all lines in my files which contain the sourceMappingUrl in my node modules. But for the case I do an npm install, those lines will come back.

I'm currently using Webpack with React.

Is there a way for Safari to ignore these lines?

Comment: exclude node_modules on webpack and turn off source map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I toggle source mapping in Safari 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550060/how-do-i-toggle-source-mapping-in-safari-7)